# flatmap for inner classes

Tags: java, java-8, flatmap

I have a `class`. I want to get list of objects that will contain all this parameters flat. For now I'm doing it with foreach. Is there a way to do it with `flatMap`?

```
public class A{
  String parA;
  List<B> parB;

  public static class B{
    String parC;
    String parD;
    List<C> parE;
  }

  public static class C{
    String parF;
    String parG;
    String parH;
    String parJ;
  }
}
```

I want to have list of objects :

```
public class Out{
  String parA;
  String parC;
  String parD;
  String parF;
  String parG;
  String parH;
  String parJ;
}
```

Comment: So, instead of having object A with String parA and List<B>, would you like to have object A with parA, parC, parD, parF... etc?

Comment: This is really unclear. Please show an example of input / output.

Comment: This is still unclear. You haven't shown what you have as input and what you want as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a given `A a = ...` the more concise and clean approach would be two nested loops like:

```
List<Out> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (B b : a.parB) {
  for (C c : b.parE) {
    list.add(new Out(a.parA, b.parC, b.parD, c.parF, c.parG, c.parH, c.parJ));
  }
}
```

Since you've asked for a `Stream` solution here you go:

```
List<Out> list = Stream.of(a).flatMap(aa -> 
  aa.parB.stream().flatMap(bb -> 
    bb.parE.stream().map(cc -> 
      new Out(aa.parA, bb.parC, bb.parD, cc.parF, cc.parG, cc.parH, cc.parJ))
  )
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what i meant!